# Finding the product from all shops, that's below the minimum limit in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

Make a group by id and get a list of the product  are below limit compare to present total stock
Id can be same, but name is unique for all id
For example, id: 1 and name can be: a, b, c, d..   Means, name will not repeat

My data List:

```
 const dataList = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "a",
      totalQty: 200,
      minimumQty: 100,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "b",
      totalQty: 90,
      minimumQty: 100,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "c",
      totalQty: 40,
      minimumQty: 50,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "a",
      totalQty: 200,
      minimumQty: 100,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "b",
      totalQty: 90,
      minimumQty: 100,
    },
  ];
  
}
```

**answer**

```
{ result : [
  {
    id: 1,
    belowLimit: [
      { name: "b", totalQty: 90 },
      { name: "c", totalQty: 40 },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    belowLimit: [
      { name: "b", totalQty: 90 },
    ],
  },
];}
```

Comment: is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/imIKPv8sCm1) what do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate([
{'$match': 
   {'$expr': {'$lt': ['$totalQty', '$minimumQty']}
   }
},
{'$group': 
   {'_id': '$id', 
    'belowLimit': {'$push': {name:'$name', qty:'$totalQty'}}
   }
}])
```

You could first select only those documents where the quantity is lesser than the required amount and after that you can group by the id of the shop

Comment: `[
  {
    _id: 1,
    belowLimit: [ { name: 'b', qty: 90 }, { name: 'c', qty: 40 } ]
  },
  { _id: 2, belowLimit: [ { name: 'b', qty: 90 } ] }
]'. I checked and this the output I got, which is what you expect if i am not wrong

Comment: can you please help to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739814/sort-data-by-selected-range-of-date-and-createdfor-from-mongodb-and-nodejs

Comment: Hey bro can you please help me to solve above question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71739814/sort-data-by-selected-range-of-date-and-createdfor-from-mongodb-and-nodejs

Comment: sure I will answer that